# Upload files to Kafka and further handling?

Tags: apache-kafka

Is it good way to send binary data of uploading files to Kafka then to distribute handling uploading by some services that are connected to Kafka topic?

I see some advantages:

- Filtering uploading data
- Replica
- Some services can handle uploading, not only one

What do you think about that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> *Is it good way to send binary data of uploading files to Kafka then to
> distribute handling uploading by some services that are connected to
> Kafka topic?*

*Typically* files are uploaded to file system and their URIs are stored in the Kafka message. This is to ensure that the Kafka message size is relatively smaller, thereby increasing the *throughput* of its clients.

In case, if we put large objects in Kafka message, the consumer would have to *read* the entire file. So your `poll()` will take longer time than usual.

On the other hand, if we just put a URI of the file instead of the file itself, then the message consumption will be relatively faster and you can delegate the processing of files to perhaps another thread (possibly from a thread pool), there by increasing your application throughput.

### Replicas

Just as there are replicas in Kafka, there can also be replicas for filesystem. Even kafka stores messages in file system (as segment files). So, the replication may as well be done with filesystem itself.

> The best way is to put an URI that points to the file in the Kafka
> message and then put a *handler* for that URI which will be
> *reponsible* for giving you the file and possibly taking care of giving you a *replica* in case the original file is deleted.

The *handler* may be loosely-coupled from the rest of your system, built specifically for managing the files, maintaining replicas etc.

### Filtering uploading data

The filtering of uploaded data can be done only when you actually *read* the contents of the file. You may do that even by putting the URI of your file in the message and reading from there. For ex, if you are using Kafka streams, you can put that filtering logic in `transform()` or `mapValues()` etc.

```
stream.from(topic)
.mapValues(v -> v.getFileURI())
.filter((k,fileURI) -> validate(read(fileURI)))
.to(..)
```

### Hitting segment.bytes

Another disadvantage of storing files in your message is that, you might hit `segment.bytes` limit if the files are larger. You need to keep changing the `segment.bytes` every time to meet the new size requirements of the files.

Another point is, if the `segment.bytes` is set to 1GB and your first message (file) size is `750MB`, and your next message is `251 MB`, the `251MB` message can't fit in the first segment, so your first segment will have only one message, though it hasn't reached the limit. This means that relatively *lower* number of messages will be stored per segment.